# Bundle builder that does not change the function param names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I am using AngularJS in my project. Now I want to bundle all my JS files into one bundle using ASP.NET's Bundling and Minification features. So after some googling, I found out that I need to create my own implementation of `IBundleBuilder`. Unfortunately, it did not go very well for me... Here's my code:

```
public class CustomBundleBuilder : IBundleBuilder
{

    public string BuildBundleContent(Bundle bundle, BundleContext context, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var parser = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser(this.ReadFile(file));
            parser.Settings.LocalRenaming = LocalRenaming.KeepAll;
            result.Append(parser.Parse(parser.Settings).ToCode());
            result.Append(";");
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

    private String ReadFile(BundleFile file)
    {
        var fileStream = file.VirtualFile.Open();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

**Notes:**

- I do not want to use the `AngularJS` optimizer.
- I was using the    library [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) and it was working
  fine, until it    started causing issues which I couldn't resolve. So
  I decided to    write my own solution.

**UPDATE:** It turned out that my code was correct and does what it's supposed to do. But I only had to clear the `Transforms` from my script bundle:

```
scriptBundle.Transforms.Clear();
```

Comment: We are using the standard bundler for our asp.net mvc 4 and angularjs project and it works fine. What is the issue you were facing which required you to create custom bundler?